# How to run background process for background fetch mode in iOS App?

Tags: ios, background-fetch

I have made a service in android native with the help of Broadcast receiver and schedule it with the Alarm Manager and this service runs in background at every 5 minutes interval. This service is running even when app is closed/terminated/forced quit or device is restarted.Its working fine as per my requirement. But now I want to run same **background process in iOS app**, means my service should run in background when app is closed or mobile device is rebooted also. Is it possible in iOS app to run background process like this?

Comment: Short answer is: There is [no reliable background fetch mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37896468/4524113).

Comment: You can use background fetch mode on iOS, but there is not specific schedule on which it will run

Comment: @Paulw11 Are there any other options to run a service on an interval? Thanks

Comment: No. The preferred approach if you need an app to have updated data regularly is to use server push